# Making the loops to handle set object type conversion of nested dictionary objects more concise

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, set

We are working to implement the following code where we must deal trying to convert the values of a dictionary into set objects. In here you see 2 dictionaries, namely `option` from `self.option` and also `option_space_dict` from `self.option_space_dict`.

In `option_space_dict`, among many other key-value pairs, the key value pair of interest which we are looking at is:

```
"extra_scripts" : [
                   ["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua",
                    "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"],
                   ["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua",
                    "Xilinx/Virtex7/xc7v2000tfhg1761-2.lua"]
                  ]
```

And we parse it to get the following 2 key value pairs each sitting in different dictionaries but grouped together in a same list, a list of the form `[dict#1, dict#2, dict#3 ... ]`:

```
# could be sitting in dict#1
"extra_scripts" : ["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua",
                   "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]
```

or

```
# could be sitting in dict#2
"extra_scripts" :  ["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua",
                    "Xilinx/Virtex7/xc7v2000tfhg1761-2.lua"]
```

and `option` is a parameter that we obtained by iterating over each item in that list using a for loop, so at any one iteration where the method `getOptionCompack` is called, `option` is just essentially any one of the `dict#1`, `dict#2` and so on in that list.

In the method `getOptionCompack`, we are trying to construct sets out of the various key-value pairs and the issue we face, **which this code has overcome**, is that we need to be able to access the nested lists to perform the `set()` conversion.

```
def getOptionCompack(self) :

  result = [] # Initialize and empty list which we will return to this function
  for k,v in self.option.iteritems():
    # The general approach:
    # Check if the value, v of the option dictionary is actually a list
    # If it is, then we must handle the value, v of the the corresponding key that is located in option_space_dictionary differently
    # by iteratively accessing each nested list item using the while loop and making each of
    # these nested lists into a set() object
    if isinstance(v, list):
      i = 0
      while i < len(self.option_space_dict[k]):
        if set(v) != set(self.option_space_dict[k][i]):
          result.append((k,v))  
        i = i+1
    else:
      if set([v]) != set(self.option_space_dict[k]):
        result.append((k,v))
  return result
```

This is primarily achieved through the loop:

```
  i = 0
  while i < len(self.option_space_dict[k]):
    if set(v) != set(self.option_space_dict[k][i]):
      result.append((k,v))  
    i = i+1
```

However, we believe there should be a better way to express this. So our questions are,

Can we perhaps use a `for` loop to replace this `while` loop?

Is it possible to use a list comprehension perform the `getOptionCompack`? We have tried with:

```
def getOptionCompack(self) :  
  return [ (k, v) for k, v in self.option.iteritems() if set([v]) != { tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in  self.option_space_dict[k] } ]
```

but this doesn't work, and we know its because we have not gone deep enough with the `self.option_space_dict[k]` term to get at the individual nested lists that the additional `i` parameter in `self.option_space_dict[k][i]` has allowed us to do. But we don't know how to go further with that in this comprehension.

Is it recommended, for the extent of looping and conditionals, that we use a list comprehension here? Or would we be more pythonic to follow the standard expression?

I know I have been quite verbose here in this post, but I thought it would be good to explain some background behind what we are trying to do better with the code here, and also share what alternative methods we have attempted but failed to successfully implement.

Any feedback comments or suggestions here will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:

```
# Your while
i = 0
while i < len(self.option_space_dict[k]):
    if set(v) != set(self.option_space_dict[k][i]):
      result.append((k,v))  
    i = i+1

# For loop
for item in self.option_space_dict[k]:
    if set(v) != set(item):
        result.append((k,v))

# As list comprehension
[(k,v) for item in self.option_space_dict[k] if set(v) != set(item)]
```

I'm only 99% sure this will work since I don't have your data to test with.

2:

I wouldn't recommend making one whole list comprehension for this method. You should keep it the way you have it. This way you can change it easier. In my opinion a list comprehension shouldn't be longer than around 80 characters. (Mine is 68)